# Removing specific users with specific information in their line in bash/unix

Tags: windows, bash, unix

I'm trying to manipulate csv data to only delete users with specific header attributes by creating a script file and running it, then it will read data from a csv and delete the users with specific information in their line... but when I run this script, it gives errors and shows information such as all the commands to use but when I go through the list of commands it gives, it doesn't work.

**mycsv.csv**

```
username,first,last,gender,dob,countries,airports,shells,cuisines,operands,water,nfl
mb8239,maaran,batey,m,april 16 1993,japan,tpa,sh,spanish,multiplication,hint,49ers
```

```bash
INPUT=mycsv.csv 
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
while read username first last gender dob countries airports shells cuisines operands water nfl
do
    if [ $shells == "sh" ]
    then
        userdel -r
    fi
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

From what I understand, if im trying to remove the users using the shell 'sh' then i would do userdel -r no?

Comment: `userdel` takes an obligatory `LOGIN` parameter, what errors do you get apart from it?

Comment: You tagged this question with both `windows` and `unix`.  Are you attempting to remove users on a windows or unix/linx?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @j_b im removing users on bash, im just using windows 11, but im removing users with the sh in their line out of the .csv file that im importing this data from

Comment: should I edit the tags?

Comment: No, seems like your tags are appropriate based on your clarification.  Further, I do not know windows at all but if you have access to `awk` you might be able to try something like `awk -F',' '(NR>1) {if ($8 ~ /sh/) {system(sudo userdel -r $1)}}' mycsv.csv`.  Note that the use of `sudo` may not be appropriate for windows, but I would image you would need some type of administrator access to remove a user.

Comment: @j_b it comes up with a new error: sh: 0sm8397: command not found but it does this for every single person in the csv file but instead of 0sm8397 it puts a 0 infront of the username and then displays the username such as the one above or : 0sm8397

Comment: Wrap the `sudo userdel -r $1` in double quotes:  ` awk -F',' '(NR>1) {if ($8 ~ /sh/) {system("sudo userdel -r $1")}}' mycsv.csv`

Comment: {Usage: userdel [options] LOGIN -- i get this error followed by a list of commands which is interesting, the error is followed by something like "Options: -f, --force then a description" and a couple of other commands like that, -h, -r, -R, -P, -Z etc

Answer (score 0):

Finally had a chance to get to my ubuntu machine and sort the awk `system()` command syntax out.  Try the following awk command:

```
awk -F',' '(NR>1) {if ($8 ~ /sh/) {out=system("sudo userdel -r " $1 ); print out}}' mycsv.csv
```

Output:

```
userdel: user 'mb8239' does not exist
6
```

The `userdel: user 'mb8239' does not exist` is the output generated by the attempted deletion of a user that does not exist on the host, so is appropriate output.   The `6` is the exit code of the `userdel` command that is also expected per the man page for `userdel` when a user does not exist:

```
EXIT VALUES
       The userdel command exits with the following values:

       0
           success

       1
           can't update password file

       2
           invalid command syntax

       6
           specified user doesn't exist

       8
           user currently logged in

       10
           can't update group file

       12
           can't remove home directory
```

If you do not care about the output from the `userdel` command then you can utilize the following to redirect the output to `/dev/null`:

```
awk -F',' '(NR>1) {if ($8 ~ /sh/) {system("sudo userdel -r " $1 " > /dev/null 2>&1")}}' mycsv.csv
```